# Web scraping directory - R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to web scraping here and I am trying to extract the information of the companies on this website: 
http://apps.asiainsurancereview.com/IDA/Asp/CompanyList.aspx?company=&type=&jobType=&country=&search=company

And the information that I want to extract is as the link below (this is the first company that is listed in the table from the first link above):

http://apps.asiainsurancereview.com/IDA/Asp/IDA_CompanyDetails.aspx?person=&designation=&company=&country=&search=company&comslno=272

I am trying to extract the details of each of the companies (phone number, email, website etc.) listed in the first link, then export them into a .csv file.

However, the issue is that the number in the website URL is not in sequence, for example, the first company's information URL is as above, ending with "comslno=272", but the second company has the URL ending with "comslno=1824"

I have tried the R codes as below (I know it might not be feasible)

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

directory <- lapply(paste0('http://apps.asiainsurancereview.com/IDA/Asp/IDA_CompanyDetails.aspx?person=&designation=&company=&country=&search=company&comslno=', 1:9999999),
                    function(url){
                      url %>% read_html() %>% 
                        html_nodes("tr td") %>% 
                        html_text()
                    })

write.csv(directory, file = "directory.csv")
```

However, it doesn't work because the URL does not work with all the numbers between 1:9999999.

For example, the URL ending with "comslno=1" and "comslno=2" exist but "comslno=3" does not exist.

Is there a way to make R ignore those non-existing URL and continue with the process? Or are there any other simpler ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `tryCatch`.

```
library(rvest)

directory <- lapply(paste0('http://apps.asiainsurancereview.com/IDA/Asp/IDA_CompanyDetails.aspx?person=&designation=&company=&country=&search=company&comslno=', 
                           c(2:5, 1)),
                    function(url) {
                      tryCatch(
                        url %>% read_html() %>%
                          html_nodes("tr td") %>% 
                          html_text(),
                        error = function(e) NULL
                        )
                    })

write.csv(do.call(rbind, directory), file = "directory.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first page (or you will need to incorporate a loop for other pages) you can use a css selector to target the appropriate nodes in the DOM and extract the appropriate attribute of those matched nodes which will give you the numbers you need to concatenate onto a base url. i show two different examples. The uncommented should be faster.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

base = 'http://apps.asiainsurancereview.com/IDA/Asp/IDA_CompanyDetails.aspx?person=&designation=&company=&country=&search=company&comslno='
p <- read_html('http://apps.asiainsurancereview.com/IDA/Asp/CompanyList.aspx?company=&type=&jobType=&country=&search=company')
#urls <- paste0(base, p %>% html_nodes('#tableList tr[id]') %>% html_attr('id'))
urls <- paste0(base, p %>% html_nodes('.select') %>% html_attr('value'))
```

You can calculate the number of pages to loop simply

```
t <- p %>% html_node('#MainContent_pagination li:last-child') %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
total_results <- as.numeric(tail(str_split(t,' ')[[1]],1))
results_per_page = 15
num_pages = ceiling(total_results / results_per_page)
```

You will make less requests overall using this strategy of looping from 1 to num_pages, gathering the actual ids then looping the final set of urls, than you would trying 1 to 9,999,999.